# Problems setting up Zuul proxy server with Eureka discovery

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to set up a zuul proxy server which will act as a gateway service for other apis in my microservice architecture.

So far all the tutorials that I have come across have the discovery client and zuul proxy set up in different gradle modules while I am trying to set them up in the same gradle module.

I have defined the routes and can see that my services have been successfully registered in the eureka dashboard. 
I have also verified that I can ping the services using a discovery client from my gatekeeper service but whenever I try to access the services from the URL, I get

"**Load balancer does not have available server for client:xyz**" 
exception.

Can somebody please help me setting this up?

Comment: That's because that setup is not recommended. It's difficult (if impossible) to get it to work.

Comment: @spencergibb May I know the reason why??

Comment: Eureka client contacts the server over http. It's not built for an embedded use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost pulled my hair out while debugging this error!